# Laptop battery stuck at 48% but won't charge or operate after 1 year of use

Tags: laptop, battery

I have a Dell Latitude E6440 my laptop battery (battery type: 71R31) stays at 48%. However, I can't charge it or even operate my laptop without the power adapter! Windows says that the battery is not charging.

The BIOS says that the battery must be replaced. This is the original battery that came with the device. I bought the device (new) one year ago, and I am not using it often, so I can't believe that my battery has died.

My BIOS is up-to-date. I am using the original adapter that shipped with my laptop. I would be happy to supply more information if required.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's definitely outside the "normal" range of li-ion battery lifetime but a failure after only a year is not unheard-of. Probably the battery has a defective cell. It happens.

Comment: The battery may be far older than the purchase date. Is there a date on the battery itself?

Comment: I didn't find any date on the battery.